# Does IIS 7 and above make automatic detection of file changes like WSGI containers, or does iis read a file each time for each request?

Tags: python, iis, scripting, wsgi

In the WSGI containers I have been using like Flask or Bottle, when a file is changed the container detects it and reloads it (as I understand it).  Is this the way IIS works?  Are pages loaded into memory and then reloaded when a change takes place (again, talking about IIS 7+).

In other words, is IIS doing what the WSGI containers are doing?  Whenever I've made changes to Classic ASP pages or PHP, it is an immediate change, but it could just be really fast reloading.  How does it work?

Does a WSGI container really load an website into memory?  IIS?  For that matter any web server/container for any technology stack?

EDIT:  By container, I mean everything that is needed to run a given stack (not the hardware, only those things directly related to the stack).  A [Java EE container](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnabo.html), to me is the combination of server and anything else I need.  A WSGI container is the same but for Python.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

I understand WSGI is a standard, but the server is implementing the standard via a process (i.e. the server).  All that together is the "container" (or so I thought.)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "WSGI container", but Flask or Bottle need to be hosted by an actual web server such as Apache (via mod_wsgi) or nginx/gunicorn. Reloading the code when the files change does not happen in these circumstances, it is something implemented by the development servers only.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're saying the "real" server will serve up my changes immediately, right?

Comment: Er, no, I was saying completely the opposite.

Comment: So how do I see my changes in deployment?

Comment: Restart the wsgi server. Ex. `sudo service uwsgi restart` would restart uwsgi, a popular wsgi server.

Comment: What Sean said. Gunicorn has a `reload` configuration setting, but that's for debugging/development only.

Comment: What if I have hundreds of users?  Won't that interrupt them?

Comment: No more than automatic reloading would. It's exactly the same. But if you have hundreds of concurrent users, you no doubt have multiple servers behind a load balancer, so you restart them one by one.

Comment: I do not.  I'll have to figure out something.  I wanted to use Python and Flask or Bottle, but this will be a hard sell.

Comment: But this is absolutely no different to any other architecture. Python app servers are not different from any others.

Comment: I'm missing something.  If I make a change to a script in IIS, I can refresh the page and see it.  I don't have to restart IIS.  I thought you were saying that if I had Apache I had to do something like apachectl restart.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into IIS refresh, which should reload a site to which you've made changes. More info in this thread:  https://serverfault.com/questions/247425/what-is-the-difference-between-iisreset-recycle-refresh-and-restart